# Does a Rogue's proficiency with a Rapier apply to the Spiral Rapier?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, rogue, proficiency

Does a Rogue's [proficiency](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Rogue/#Weapon_and_Armor_Proficiency) with a [Rapier](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/rapier) apply to the [Spiral Rapier](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/rapier-spiral/)?

Comment: [Different weapons, similar issues.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134794/8610)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, rapier proficiency could apply to the Spiral Rapier.

In the general case, proficiency with an exotic weapon (such as the Spiral Rapier) requires the [Exotic Weapon Proficiency](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/exotic-weapon-proficiency-combat/) feat.  However, the [spiral rapier's description](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/rapier-spiral/) mentions the following:

> Any effects that apply to rapiers also apply to a spiral rapier.

[Rogues](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/) specifically are proficient with [rapiers](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/rapier/), despite lacking martial weapon proficiency. While the mechanical term "effect" is not strictly defined, a character's weapon proficiency is as much an effect as any rapier-relevant feats or features. Thus, as written, their proficiency with rapiers could also apply to a spiral rapier.

By extension, this would suggest that any character proficient with all martial weapons would therefore be proficient with spiral rapiers. Due to the exotic weapon requirement, this ruling may be a stretch, and maybe not what the designers intended. Either way, this interpretation seems fair; the spiral rapier is functionally just a rapier with small conditional bonuses, at the cost of a higher base price.

Comment: The proficiency requirement is not "an effect that apply to rapiers", is it?

Comment: 1) Where's the definition of effect? 2) This leads to everyone with proficiency with all martial weapons being proficient with the spiral rapier. Both should be mentioned in the answer. (On the first point, I don't think there is one; if you've one, that's awesome, but that's an otherwise risky leap. The second point an *Adventurers' Armory 2* author obliquely addresses in [this thread](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ufiy?Spiral-Rapier-Proficiency-Question); feel free to include this research in the answer.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan That would be odd. Maybe it's a case of specific versus general? Or perhaps martial weapon proficiency would indeed give spiral rapier proficiency. It's only slightly better than a regular rapier, although it bypasses the usual requirement for Exotic Weapon proficiency. This could be a design oversight, which is not surprising for Paizo.

Comment: Language like this is not intended to include proficiency: it is meant to allow feats (like weapon specialisation) and class features (like swashbucklers' finesse) to apply as well. The long version (as intended) is: "When you are proficient, treat this weapon as a rapier for all intents and purposes"

Comment: @ThisIsMe RE: "The long version (as intended) is: 'When you are proficient, treat this weapon as a rapier for all intents and purposes.'" Can a link be provided to a designer explaining what the language intends? That is, it sounds like that comment disagrees with this answer, but there's designer commentary *agreeing* with this answer that can be found in my comment [here.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154547/does-a-rogues-proficiency-with-a-rapier-apply-to-the-spiral-rapier#comment402397_154555)

Comment: @enkryptor It's also not an effect that applies to spiral rapiers, because there's no such thing as a 'proficiency requirement'.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer so how do you call this, when you need the proficiency in order to avoid –4 penalty on attack rolls?

Answer (score 2):

Since the Spiral Rapier has "Proficiency: Exotic" (as stated in the statistics for the weapon in the SRD), a character would have to take the "Exotic Weapon Proficiency (Combat)" feat in order to wield it without penalty.

---

*Pathfinder Core Rulebook (p. 123, 4th printing):*

> **Exotic Weapon Proficiency (Combat)**
>
> Choose one type of exotic weapon, such as the spiked chain or whip. You
>   understand how to use that type of exotic weapon in combat, and can utilize any special tricks or qualities that exotic weapon might allow.
>
> **Prerequisite**: Base attack bonus +1.
>
> **Benefit**: You make attack rolls with the weapon normally.
>
> **Normal**: A character who uses a weapon with which he is not proficient takes a -4 penalty on attack rolls.
>
> [...]

Comment: Note that many exotic weapons-- possibly including the spiral rapier-- allow characters other than those with this specific feat to become proficient with them via e.g. racial familiarity or a specific allowance in a class proficiency list (e.g. the 'rapier' entry in the rogue list, which this question is about and this answer ignores).  Note also that *all* exotic weapons allow a character to gain proficiency without this feat by means of magic items (e.g. an *Opalescent White Pyramid Ioun Stone*).